# How to have different contextual voice commands menu when using CardScrollView?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am using a CardScrollView that has many cards on it. The thing is, I want to use voice commands to control them. However, depending on the card, different voice commands should be available. I haven't been able to change the contextual voice commands menu for each specific card. I tried using the onPrepareOptionsMenu which I would use on mobile Android, but it looks like it doesnt work here. Any pointers on this?

Answer (score 2):

Everytime your CardScrollView changes positions (or something happens that requires different voice menu items), try calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. Also make sure you are configuring your menu items in `onPreparePanel(int featureId, View view, Menu menu)` not onPrepareOptionsMenu as onPrepareOptionsMenu does not apply for voice initiated actions.

Note that if you want to disambiguate between a click and voice action in onPreparePanel, the featureId will be `WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS` (https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/view/WindowUtils) for voice commands and `Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL` for clicks.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - I've been trying to dynamically alter the voice menu and struggling to get onPrepareOptionsMenu to do the update. Now I know why!